# How to access setOnClickListener of a button in custom view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I am very new to Android Development and this is my first Android App.

Here is how my MainActivity layout looks like:

[image]

And this is the Component Tree of the MainActivity

[image]

The gridView is a custom view and I have a `resetGrid` function in it which looks something like this

```
public class GridView extends View {

    resetGird(){
        // stuff that resets grid;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem I am facing:

I can access the `setOnClickListener` of the reset button in the `MainActivity` file but not in the `GridView` file where the `resetGrid` function is located.

```
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(PathFind.this, "reset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I want to access this `setOnClickListener` of the reset button in the `GridView` file also and call the `resetGrid` function whenever the button is pressed.

Not only that, my plan is to use all the controls listed in the image (start button, diagonal checkbox, speed slider) to control the GridView. But I can't seem to find a way to do that.
All the controls are available in the main_activity but I can't use them in the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right way.
The "trick" is to save GridView's instance in a MainActivity variable and then use its reference to call/execute GridView's methods (like "resetGrid()").

ResetButton lives OUTSIDE GridView so it's a bad pratice to reference "resetButton" from INSIDE GridView extended class.

Pseudo code:

```
class GridView extends View {
    public void resetGrid() {
       ...do reset stuff here...
    }
}

class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GridView mGridView;
    private Button mResetButton;
    public onCreateView() {
        ...
        mGridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        mResetButton = findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGridView.resetGrid();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this worked finally, I actually tried doing this before but I forgot the 
`mGridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview);`
line so it wasn't working.